# pi zero portable mp3 player software

Tags: python, pi-zero

i am thinking about a project for which i could use some guidance.
i want to build a flac/ high bitrate mp3 player with nice clicky buttons and rotary encoders.
i have a raspberry pi zero, a dac hat which uses the i2s interface, a small low res screen and said buttons. i dont quite know how to go about the software side.
i want the software to be pretty simple,  i dont need a search function or even playlists. i want one list of high quality audio files, volume settings, skip button, etc. basic functionalities.
do you guys know of anything that allready exists or do i need to write my own code? if so, how would you guys go about that? ive read that since i would need a simple gui i could go with pygame, but honestly i dont really know how to start with that. i would appreciate links to related topics/guides.

this would be my first real pi project, i only did nextcloud before. i am a beginner at python but have a degree in comp sci, so if pointed to the right direction i could figure stuff out.

thanks for the replies.

Comment: Did you get to do it? I am strongly considering doing it so that I can have a separate portable device I can use in addition to my phone. So far it seems possible, even with the pi pico, which seems more suitable for the job, but seems like everything needs to be coded from scratch